# jQuery-Validation-Engine required only if value of another field is x or y

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

```
    "requiredInFunction": {
                "regex": "none",
                "func": function(field, rules, i, options){
                    if (field.val() === '' && $('#CartItem_vision').val()==="Progressive") {
                        return false;

                    }
                    if (field.val() === '' && $('#CartItem_vision').val()==="Bifocal")
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                "alertText": "Addition is Required"
            },
```

validate[custom[requiredInFunction]]

This validation does not do anything.

unless I put validate[required, custom[requiredInFunction]], but it becomes required even if the CartItem_vision is not "Progressive" or "Bifocal". I want them to be only required if value is "Progressive" or "Bifocal".

Answer (score 1):

In your function you can add

`rules.push('required');`

Like this :

```
function checkCell(field, rules, i, options){
    if ($('#cellNum').val().length > 0 && field.val().length == 0) {
        rules.push('required'); 
        return "Provider necessary with phone number";
    }
}
```

This means that if #cellNum is populated then the provider is necessary.
The initialization is :

```
<select name="provider" id="provider" class="validate[funcCall[checkCell]">
```